# Expecting function to be called on very simple service

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I've made an extremely simple service in order to check my sanity when it comes to testing. Here it is:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .service('TestService', TestService);

    function TestService() {
        function foo() {
            bar();
        }
        function bar() {
            console.log('Hello world!');
        }
        return {
            foo: foo,
            bar: bar
        };
    }
}());
```

So nothing complex here - foo() calls bar() which outputs a simple 'Hello World' message to the console. My test for this looks like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    fdescribe('test.service',function() {
        var testService;
        beforeEach(module('app'));
        beforeEach(inject(function(_TestService_) {
            testService = _TestService_;
        })); 

        describe('setup',function() {
            it('should get the testService',function() {
                expect(testService).not.toBe(undefined);
            });
        });
        describe('foo()',function() {
            fit('should call bar',function() {
                spyOn(testService,'bar');
                testService.foo();
                expect(testService.bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        });
    });
}());
```

All I'm doing here is checking to see of foo calls bar in the usual method i.e. spying on bar. But this gives me the error:

```
Expected spy bar to have been called
```

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this one out as this cannot be something complicated - What am I fundamentally doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: one thing that I might suspect that, when you user .service(), you should not return an object, otherwise use factory like angular.module('abc').factory()

Comment: Why do you have underscores on either side of `_TestService_`? I've never needed to do anything like that in my tests.

Comment: @HankScorpio for convenience and maintainability http://stackoverflow.com/a/15318137/1230663

Comment: what @br3w5 said - it's the underscore notation that allows you to use the service name as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what the problem is.
When you spy on `testService, 'bar'`, jasmine will replace the 'bar' property on `testService` with a spy, however internally your service `foo()` has no reference to the `testService` object, so therefore it can never call that spy.

Try this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .service('TestService', TestService);

    function TestService() {
        var service = {};
        service.foo = function() {
            service.bar();
        };
        service.bar = function() {
            console.log('Hello world!');
        };
        return service;
    }
}());
```

Comment: That did fix it but I don't really understand why there are two different references - surely spies should be referring to the function on the testService as opposed to essentially creating their own stand alone reference?

Comment: Consider this: create a function `function foo(){ ... }` and 2 objects that each reference it `var a = {beep: foo}; var b = {beep: foo};`. Next do this: `a.beep = someOtherFunction;` <<That's what jasmine is doing. It won't change `b.beep` to `someOtherFunction` because it can't. There's no way for it to be aware of other references to `foo` so anything else that references `foo` will stay intact. Even if all other references to `foo` are changed to something else, the function will still exist in memory because `b` still references it.
Does that make more sense?

Comment: To be clear `testService` in your test refers to the object you created on your return line `return { ... };`. It doesn't refer to the `TestService()` method. `TestService` doesn't have a `foo` or a `bar` property.

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense - thanks for the help Hank and good luck with your world domination plans :)