# Cannot read property 'href' of undefined error in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test my router functionality .I am getting this error
**Cannot read property 'href' of undefined**
 ..could you please tell me how i will remove this error

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/mZiNteMWqS4forycMHiK?p=preview

```
describe('router  check', function(){



  describe('router check',function(){
     var view = 'partials/state1.html',
     $state;

     var $scope;
   beforeEach(function(){
    module('app');
   });

   beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$templateCache,$state) {
     $state=$state;
     $templateCache.put(view, '');
        }));

         it('should map state state1 to url /state1 ', function() {
            expect($state.href('state1', {})).to.equal('/state1');
        });

        it('should map /state1 route to state1 View template', function () {
            expect($state.get('state1').templateUrl).to.equal(view);
        });


  })
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318096/what-does-the-underscores-in-servicename-mean-in-angularjs-tests

Comment: still facing issue http://plnkr.co/edit/mZiNteMWqS4forycMHiK?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you aren't accessing $state in the right scope. The statement $state=$state in beforeEach doesn't assign the state to variable "$state" declared within describe.

Try

```
describe('router check',function(){
 var view = 'partials/state1.html',
 $state_test;

 var $scope;


   beforeEach(function(){
    module('app');
   });

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$templateCache,$state) {
         $state_test=$state;
         $templateCache.put(view, '');
            }));
```

Answer (score 2):

There were few issues with your code. I have fixed them and its working as expected.

Link to [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHqKxcdSvUFoRsp5tkyI?p=preview)

```
describe('router  check', function(){
  describe('router check',function(){
     var view = 'partials/state1.html',
     $state, $templateCache, $scope;

   beforeEach(function(){
    module('app');

    inject(function(_$state_, _$templateCache_) {
      $state = _$state_;
      $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
    });

     $templateCache.put(view, '');
   });

    it('should map state state1 to url /state1 ', function() {
        expect($state.href('state1', {})).toEqual('#/state1');
    });

    it('should map /state1 route to state1 View template', function () {

      expect($state.get('state1').views.testView.templateUrl).toEqual(view);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Check the plunkr again. I have updated it so the test passes.